# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, nonetype, operands

I have a list with a single value in it, populated in one function.
I have another function that I want to take that value, divide it by 2, and place it into another list.

I've found similar issues, but none seem to be exactly the same as mine and the fixes don't seem to work for my issue.

```
from random import randint
import random

finalList = [None] * 100
firstList = [None] * 30
secondList = []

def funcOne():
    global firstList
    
    for b in range(1):
        firstList.append(random.randrange(11,12,1))

    return firstList


def funcTwo():
    global finalList

    finalList[0] = firstList
    for i in firstList:
        secondList.append(i/2)
    finalList[1] = 5 + secondList

    return finalList
    print(finalList)

funcOne()
funcTwo()
```

I'm receiving the:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
  File "C:\Users\redy\OneDrive\Documents\RPG\Biographies\TLoE_Codes\from random import randint.py", line 22, in funcTwo
    secondList.append(i/2)
  File "C:\Users\redy\OneDrive\Documents\RPG\Biographies\TLoE_Codes\from random import randint.py", line 29, in <module>
    funcTwo()
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: As an aside, you only need `global` when _assigning_ a variable outside of the function's scope. You are updating existing values, so `global` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstList` starts out containing thirty copies of `None`.

Then in `funcTwo()` when you do this:

```
for i in firstList:
    secondList.append(i/2)
```

The first value in `firstList` is None, so this code tries to calculate `None/2`, which is an error.

Comment: I had an error before (when I had just firstList = []) stating that I couldn't use finalList[0] = firstList because 'list assignment index out of range', and I came across a post saying that this could be worked around by adding the 100 * None to the list

Answer (score 0):

During iteration you assigned `i = None`,
and then tried to compute the expression `None / 2`.
Don't do that, as it won't work, it will give the TypeError you reported.

Prefer to assign a numeric quantity to `i`, and *then* divide it by 2.

Answer (score 0):

You append to `firstList`, a list starting with 100 Nones. The first 100 elements will yield None/2. Initialize it as `firstList = []`.

Also, what do you suppose `for b in range(1):` does?

Comment: An error I was coming across before was saying that I couldn't assign anything to my empty firstList because firstList[0] is out of index range. I came across several posts suggesting to add the 100 * None to the list to start with. As far as I was aware, for b in range(1): is supposed to iterate through a list and append a random number between the stated range into the list

Comment: You can't assign to an index not allocated by the list. E.g. `list = []` `list[3] = "foo"` wouldn't work. That's when you can use the None initialization method if you know you're going to need a certain number of indices. However, you're _appending_, which adds a new element to the end of the list. In this case, the 101st element becomes the random value; index 0-99 are all None.

Comment: Also, that's not what `range(1)` does. `range` in basics takes your input value N and creates a list of indices which it iterates over. E.g. `for x in range(5):` `print(x)` would print the numbers 0 through 4.